# symfony security restrict access to a list of route to specified set of ips

Tags: security, symfony, firewall

I've got a Symfony application and need to restrict access to a list of paths to a specified set of ips.

This is needed for a site that is still in development, but will be put live in stages. The paths that are done should be accessible to anyone.

Other paths should only be accessible from a specified set of ip addresses.
Otherwise a simple 403 should be shown.

The paths do not share the same prefix.
I also do not want to temporary change the actual paths.

What would be the best approach to do this? 
Adding a huge list of items in access_control does not feel like a good idea.

Can I add a firewall listener or something that can check both ip and the requested path? Can I throw a simple AccessDenied exception from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to configure it in your security.yml under access_control

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    ryan:
                        password: ryanpass
                        roles: 'ROLE_USER'
                    admin:
                        password: kitten
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'     

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER, host: symfony\.com$ }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, methods: [POST, PUT] }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

instead of ip you can use also `ips: [1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8]`

Roles get from your provider, in example above it is added right inside the config.

All about it is here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html

It would be good to read the whole security section also:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#roles

Comment: is ROLE_USER_IP a reserved role in symfony? or just an example. It did not work for me.....
I seem to have it working using the following to rules for 1 path:
        - { path: ^/example, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER ], ips: %ips_testing% }
        - { path: ^/example, roles: ROLE_ACCESS_DENIED }
Where the second rule would kick the visitor out if the first one does not match.

Comment: @DoppyNL no ROLE_USER_IP is not reserved its just an example... you can create role names on your own in the same config. .. the rule is they need to start with ROLE_ ... I'll update my anwer

Comment: The security component will stop checking rules when OR a rule matches completely OR a user does not have the specified ROLE. When the ip is not matched it will try the next rule. That is why you need to add another rule for the same path buth with an non-existing ROLE to actually deny access. See the cookbook link used in the answer, it is explained quite detailed there.